# Image Squences AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I am very new to ANDENGINE. I am trying to work on animated sprites now at that time I have sprite animated object like `image1`, `image2` ,`image3` . In these images a sequence of animation will be performed . Now in ANDENGINE for animation `TiledTextureRegion` is used which use only one image in which sprite animations are given like  image below so is there any way to run a sprites animation using image sequences. I searched a lot on it, but it appears that there is very few information on that topic because andengine give ease but at that time I have to do that, and I am unable to think that how to start or use any method to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Btw, your first and last image in the sequence look identical. So you probably only need one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much I get your question, you can't play an animation with several individual images. You should use only one Tiled image to achieve animation for a single sprite. The above image is ok to play a run animation. Why you searched to combine individual sprite for animation ?

For above image animation you can use

```
    yourSprite.animate(new long[] { 110, 110, 110, 110 ,110 }, 0, 4, true);
```

In this animate method you have four parameters. First parameters is responsible for each tiled animate duration, Second Parameter (here :0) is the starting index of the tiled sprite, 
Third parameter, (here :4)is the last index of the Tiled. Fourth parameters are a boolean value to looping the animation.

NB: I ignore your second row Tiled on above image here. 
happy coding:)

Comment: That's only 99% true. You can feed a ``TiledTextureRegion`` with an arbitrary amount of ``ITextureRegion``s (, which itself can be ``TiledTextureRegion`` (inception!!!)). See: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2-AnchorCenter/src/org/andengine/opengl/texture/region/TiledTextureRegion.java#L30

Answer (score 1):

You can create a TiledTextureRegion from a folder. The example below loads all the images from the folder "person" because its a walk cycle of a person.

```
BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas texture = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(engine.getTextureManager(), 256, 64);                     
personTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAssetDirectory(texture, context.getAssets(), "person");
try {
        texture.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(0, 1, 4));
        texture.load();
} catch (TextureAtlasBuilderException e) {
        Debug.e(e);
}
```

The images will be added in alphabetical order.